How do I move part of one pdf page onto another pdf page
I have a 2-page PDF document. I would like to create a new one-page PDF document with part of p1 of the original document and part of p2 (see image link):

What is the best way to do this?

Roughly, untested:

Split into two:

cpdf in.pdf 1 -o 1.pdf
cpdf in.pdf 2 -o 2.pdf

Now, move the contents of the second page down:

cpdf -shift "0 dy" 2.pdf -o shifted.pdf

Now, crop around the box you want to clip:

cpdf -cropbox "x y w h" shifted.pdf -o cropped.pdf

Now, set the crop box in stone by clipping to it:

cpdf -hard-box /CropBox cropped.pdf -o clipped.pdf

Now, stamp one file onto the other:

cpdf -stamp-on clipped.pdf 1.pdf -o final.pdf
You will need to pick appropriate values for dy, x, y, w, h.
If you have more than two pages, you can substitute cpdf in.pdf odd -o 1.pdf and cpdf in.pdf even -o 2.pdf at the beginning to do it all in one go.

Please add to your answer where I can find cpdf. I don't have it installed as part of the many pdf-handling packages I already have installed, and pacman -S cpdf isn't found.

I did pip install cpdf then cpdf  ticket.pdf 1 -o ticket-p1.pdf; and it says, "Usage: cpdf [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...and gives the possible commands:extract-images, 2-up, cat, meta, extract-text. I'm thinking I have the wrong cpdf`?

Yes, you have the wrong cpdf. https://community.coherentpdf.com/

Thank you for introducing me to this library. I've been getting by with pdfcrop, pdfnup, pdftk, etc., etc. This one looks like it will do everything like ImageMagick for PDFs.

What worked best for me in this case is: https://paste.rs/rzUxH. Since each page has a mess on the bottom half of the page, I need to crop them both, so I first create a blank page, then "stamp" each ticket onto that blank page. It looks perfect.

One goal is to avoid "rasterization" of the document. Letters should still be "letters" (rather than pictures of letters) and any images in the input PDF should be retained in their original glory and not resampled. I'm pretty sure the approach outlined here achieves that.
In general, the approach is:

Isolate each input part into its own PDF file
Create a blank PDF with the desired final dimensions
(Ab)use pdftk to place the parts onto the blank document

It seems like it should be possible to skip step 1 above and do it as part of step 3, but I couldn't figure out how to 1) pick a page from the input and 2) crop the input page before inserting into the blank document.
Detailed steps

Create a "workspace" directory

mkdir pdftk && cd pdftk;


Place the input file

cp ~/Downloads/ticket.pdf .;


Create a blank PDF that matches the desired final dimensions

magick xc:none -page Letter a.pdf;


Isolate input page 1 (and similarly for page 2)

pdftk ticket.pdf cat 1 output ticket-p1.pdf


Crop input pages

pdfcrop --margins '0 0 0 -440' ticket-p1.pdf ticket-p1-cropped.pdf


git clone 'https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk.git' source;
cd source && git checkout origin/master
mvn package -DskipTests=true

Initial build to make sure you have everything you need. Fix any build errors now (correct jdk on path, etc.).


Apply the following patch
diff --git a/java/com/gitlab/pdftk_java/filter.java 
b/java/com/gitlab/pdftk_java/filter.java
index c2b92d5..dea82e9 100644
--- a/java/com/gitlab/pdftk_java/filter.java
+++ b/java/com/gitlab/pdftk_java/filter.java
@@ -415,7 +415,7 @@ class filter {

      float[] trans = null;
       if (mark_page_rotation == 0) {
-          trans = new float[] {mark_scale, 0, 0, mark_scale, h_trans, v_trans};
+          trans = new float[] {1, 0, 0, 1, (float)40, (float)450};
       } else if (mark_page_rotation == 90) {
         trans =
             new float[] {


As you can see from the diff, you can scale and translate your input as desired.


Run the modified code

mvn package -DskipTests=true
cd target/
java -jar pdftk-java-*.jar ../../blank.pdf background ../../ticket-p1-cropped.pdf output ../../phase1.pdf


Touch up filter.java again and create the second phase:

java -jar pdftk-java-*.jar ../../phase1.pdf background ../../ticket-p2-cropped.pdf output ../../phase2.pdf



